# New Selenium IDE, how to write a conditional statement with stored attribute

Tags: javascript, java, testing, selenium-ide

I was able to store the alt value attribute. now i want to write a condition statement that says,

if the Stored attribute is "iwantthistextvalue" then true.

this is what i am trying that is not working

```
${x} === "iwantthistextvalue"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use approach as i mentioned in screenshot below.

Replace command where I store variable with 'store attribute'

[image]

Comment: the screenshot is broken

Comment: here is more for context

Answer (score -1):

Here is Selenium IDE code: [if...else condition code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylf2f.png)

Side by side, you can see the original documentation of control flow from Selenium IDE. That section describes all possible control flow & conditional commands. Check this link, it is really very helpful:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27017338)

Comment: Thanks @DavidvanDriessche, actually I'm new here and did not realize the issue you've mentioned. I'll keep this in mind and will try to edit my answer with better help.

Comment: Hi @DavidvanDriessche, I've edited my answer and added code now (as screenshot). Hope it'll be helpful this time.